# Unable to install Atmel Studio 7

Tags: windows, installation, windows-7-x64, atmelstudio, avr-studio7

I am trying to install Atmel Studio 7. I have download the setup from [here](http://www.atmel.com/tools/atmelstudio.aspx#download). But when I try to install the software I got this error:-
[image]

So, I update my windows but result is same. I have tried online installer, and offine installer as well but result is same in both cases.
Can anyone tell me how to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to install my setup. Actually I was installing the latest version of Atmel Studio 7. But this time I download an older version of my software from [here](http://www.atmel.com/tools/studioarchive.aspx). This time installation goes fine. I still do not know how to install latest version, so I am still waiting for some answers.

Comment: Can you tell us which version did you install please?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply install the offline version using this parameter (with Command Prompt): /SystemValidationErrorAsWarning

More Help:
Go to "Start" -> Run -> Type "CMD"   ||||  or Press keys => "Windows + R"
Point to the directory where the installer is.
type the below command and press enter:

```
as-installer-7.0.1645-full.exe /SystemValidationErrorAsWarning
```

Follow the installer and complete the installation to the end.